# How to download an .apk with ktor library and kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, download, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I'm using the Ktor library (io.ktor:ktor-client-android:1.2.5) for downloading files.

When I download an image everything is fine, but when I want to download an .apk, it doesn't work.

I'm using [ktor](https://ktor.io/) 1.2.5.

This is the function that I use:

```
    suspend fun HttpClient.downloadFile(file: OutputStream, url: String): Flow<DownloadResult> {
    return flow {
        try {
            val response = call {
                url(url)
                method = HttpMethod.Get
            }.response
            val data = ByteArray(response.contentLength()!!.toInt())
            var offset = 0

            do {
                val currentRead = response.content.readAvailable(data, offset, data.size)
                offset += currentRead
                val progress = (offset * 100f / data.size).roundToInt()
                emit(DownloadResult.Progress(progress))
            } while (currentRead > 0)

            response.close()

            if (response.status.isSuccess()) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    file.write(data)
                    //file.write()
                }
                emit(DownloadResult.Success)
            } else {
                emit(DownloadResult.Error("File not downloaded"))
            }
        } catch (e: TimeoutCancellationException) {
            emit(DownloadResult.Error("Connection timed out", e))
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            emit(DownloadResult.Error("Failed to connect. ${t.message}"))
        }
    }
}
```

And I use it like tthis:

```
private fun downloadFile(view: View, context: Context, url: String, file: Uri) {
        val ktor = HttpClient(Android)

        //viewModel.setDownloading(true)
        context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(file)?.let { outputStream ->
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                ktor.downloadFile(outputStream, url).collect {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        when (it) {
                            is DownloadResult.Success -> {
                                //viewModel.setDownloading(false)
                                view.custom_des_pb_progreso_descarga.progress = 0
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Descarga Completa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                                dismiss()
                                viewFile(file, context)
                            }

                            is DownloadResult.Error -> {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Error al descargar actualización. ${it.message}  ${it.cause} ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                                dismiss()
                            }

                            is DownloadResult.Progress -> {
                                view.custom_des_pb_progreso_descarga.progress = it.progress
                                view.custom_des_pb_conteo_descarga.text = "${it.progress}%"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone know what might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend starting with the simplest possible code for downloading files and then add more complexity (flow and `DownloadResult`) while checking every step of the way. Here is the working code that just downloads a file:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val client = HttpClient(Android)

        runBlocking {
            client.downloadFile(
                "https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=de/sweetcode/e/1.7.2-alpha/e-1.7.2-alpha.jar",
                applicationContext.openFileOutput("result.jar", MODE_PRIVATE)
            )
        }
    }
}

suspend fun HttpClient.downloadFile(url: String, output: OutputStream) {
    get<HttpStatement>(url).execute { response ->
        response.content.copyTo(output)
    }
}
```